# How to use nested alias to make the query simpler?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, alias

Let's say I have this query:`

```
SELECT
    IF(uPer="Yes", "Y", "N") AS Manage,
    IF(date_check="Yes", "Y", "N") As dCheck,
    IF(dCheck="Yes", "Great", "Not Great") AS firstNested,
    IF(firstNested="Great",1,0) AS secondNested
FROM table
```

So in this example I have more that 1 alias and I want to use some of them inside other aliases , Like a nested aliases.

How to achieve that without copying/pasting  alias inside another alias like:

```
IF(
   IF(dCheck="Yes", "Great", "Not Great") AS firstNested) ="Great",1,0
) AS secondNested
```

Note sure if the above is a right syntax.

Comment: You nee to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Manage,
    dCheck,
    firstNested,
    IF(firstNested="Great",1,0) AS secondNested
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Manage,
        dCheck,
        IF(dCheck="Yes", "Great", "Not Great") AS firstNested
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF(uPer="Yes", "Y", "N") AS Manage,
            IF(date_check="Yes", "Y", "N") As dCheck
            FROM table
    ) as t1
) as t2
```

Bug: `dCheck` result will be `Y` or `N` and you are checking `Yes` in the next test which will result false and `firstNested` will be `Not Great` for all the rows.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT
    Manage,
    dCheck,
    firstNested,
    IF(firstNested="Great",1,0) AS secondNested
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Manage,
        dCheck,
        IF(dCheck="Y", "Great", "Not Great") AS firstNested
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF(uPer="Yes", "Y", "N") AS Manage,
            IF(date_check="Yes", "Y", "N") As dCheck
            FROM table
    ) as t1
) as t2
```